# String comparisons not comparing

Tags: string, powershell

I am trying run a Powershell script to delete certain files in a directory. The name must contain `blahblahblah` for me to be able to delete this.

In my test sub directory, I have several files with this in the name. However when I execute the following code:

`$itemsToDelete = get-childItem -path $pathName | where {$_.Name -contains blahblahblah"}`

It does not select any items.

I have triple checked to make sure that I am in the correct directory when executing the script.

**EDIT**

As it has been pointed out to me. I was using `contains` incorrectly.

```
$itemsToDelete = get-childItem -path $pathName | where {($_.Name).Contains("blahblahblah")}
```

correctly cured my confusion.

Comment: `-contains` [doesn't work like you probably think it should work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx). It's not your fault - the name of the operator is misleading. Anyway, just use `-match` instead.

Comment: You are correct.  `where {($_.Name).Contains("blahblahblah")` . This works. Thank you. If you would like to post an answer, I will gladly except.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting my comment (with some background) at the author's request.

A quote from [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759%28v=wps.620%29.aspx):

```
-Contains
  Description: Containment operator. Tells whether a collection of reference
  values includes a single test value. Always returns a Boolean value. Returns TRUE
  only when the test value exactly matches at least one of the reference values. 

  When the test value is a collection, the Contains operator uses reference
  equality. It returns TRUE only when one of the reference values is the same
  instance of the test value object.
```

In short, `-Contains` doesn't let you check if a string contains a specific substring. You want `-Match` or `-Like` for that. Note that `-Match` treats your test value like a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) so you may need to escape special characters.

My opinion is that `-Contains` is neither very intuitive nor very helpful. Theoretically speaking such things make sense if you support ["don't program by coincidence"](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence) idea but for a scripting language they are somewhat overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using `-like` (`-unlike`) combined with wild char `*` to match your search. This more like the `like` in SQL.

```
$itemsToDelete = get-childItem -path $pathName | where { $_.Name -like '*blahblahblah*' }
```

Comment: While this was already done in the comments if nothing else you should at least explain why your solution will help the OP's situation.